# Problems with Directx Header file

Tags: directx, visual-studio-2013, directx-11

Hi I am trying to use the Visual Studio 2013 Graphics debugger and tried to create an event group. Bute I ran into a problem while including d3d11_1.h header file . I copied the header to my include directory in June 2010 SDK's include file. But the following error pops up.

**1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dxgi1_2.h(1271): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int**

**1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dxgi1_2.h(1271): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'**

**1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dxgi1_2.h(1275): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DXGI_RGBA'**

I am have also copied over dxgi1_2.h in the include directory . What is causing this problem ? Is it a conflict problem ? Can any one give me any pointer on how to create this event group ?

Comment: I have 3 hypotheses: (1) you forgot to `#include <windows.h>`; (2) you forgot somewhere header guard (such as `#pragma once`); (3) you do something wrong with includes. Show us relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was due to the header orders, you placed the DirectX headers before windows headers, so some types defined in windows.h was not visible when the compiler process directx headers.

You should include windows.h in prior to the direct3d headers.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
...
```